# Cannot import XLSX file

Tags: r, import, xlsx

I am trying to import an XLSX file into R to begin my class project. It is giving me issues, as it returns a result with 0 variables. I have tried to rework the pathway to the file multiple times with no different result. Anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

My input:

```
customer_data <- fread("~C:\\matly\\Desktop\\Grad School\\Class 4\\Customer.xlsx", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The output:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Warning messages:
1: In (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
  '(~C:\matly\Desktop\Grad School\Class 4\Customer.xlsx) > C:\Users\matly\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGs4FDg\file434f8231' execution failed with error code 1
2: In fread("~C:\\matly\\Desktop\\Grad School\\Class 4\\Customer.xlsx",  :
  File 'C:\Users\matly\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGs4FDg\file434f8231' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

Comment: `fread` doesn't read XLSX files, for that you need for instance package `readxl`, function `read_excel`.

Comment: also, not sure what that tilde (`~`) is doing at the beginning of your file name ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least two issues here:

- you have a bogus-looking tilde (`~`) at the beginning of your file name
- `data.table::fread()` reads "delimited" files (i.e., space or whitespace or tab or comma-separated), not XLSX files

Try e.g.

```
readxl::read_excel("C:/matly/Desktop/Grad School/Class 4/Customer.xlsx")
```

Other style points:

- `read_excel` automatically uses `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`; it returns a "tibble", which is almost (but not quite!) the same as a data frame
- using `/` as a path separator works cross-platform and is a little easier to read
- I'd strongly encourage you to change your working directory and use *relative* path names, e.g.

```
setwd("C:/matly/Desktop/Grad School/Class 4/")
readxl::read_excel("Customer.xlsx")
```